# Beveling a rounded corner until the beveled edges meet at a point

Tags: bevel

I'm trying to continue beveling this rounded corner until it meets at a point without beveling too high on the z-axis.

[image]

[image]

If I use percent and set it to 100.00% it only works on the two long sides and not the corner. Could there be something wrong with my topology?

[image] [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is definitely topology. You have a lone vertex that the bevel must eventually reach which, precisely because it's a lone vertex, and not a series of subdivided edges, will never be able to be reached (red arrow). You need a number of subdivisions at that location which matches the number of subdivisions for the row of edges to be beveled (represented here by the green line and dots).

[image]

Instead, rebuild the floor as follows:

[image]

Now, when you select the line of edges where the wall and floor meet, and perform a bevel, you get this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you both so much! Problem solved! I needed the extra topology. I deleted that face and created a new face without the corner and the lone vertex. I took the new face, inset it to get a new corner with connecting topology. I then beveled the corner edges using the Percent setting set at 100%. It's mint!

Answer (score 4):

To bevel right to your edges you need to change the bevel tool from offset mode to percent mode and then set the value to 100%.
[image]

Comment: I edited my post for more detail. The percent worked on the long sides, bot not the corner. For some reason the corner is beveling the wrong edges to 100%? Even when I try to only bevel one edge of the corner, it bevels to the edge above it on the z-axis.